# Seperate protection circuit for charger and system for Li-ion battery

Tags: lithium-ion, circuit-protection

I'm thinking of using the BQ2971x for battery protection.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2971.pdf

One thing that anoys me is that most batterys (18650 Li-ions) usually have a lot higher discharge than charge current.

So using one like this:
Would imply that it has to be configured for maximum charge due to that the charge current is alot lower than what the discharged is allowed to be.

[image]

To go around the problem I've this idea of using two BQ2971x instead, like this:
By that way I can configure the discharge and charge current separetly by selecting different mosfets or variants of the BQ271x.

[image]

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: @Finbarr if there might be any problems I haven't thought of

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to do here. As with 99% of questions involving charging of batteries, the correct solution is to use a proper charger.